# Unable to install web3.py on Windows: Cannot open include file: 'io.h':

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, web3.py, ganache

I am unable to perform the pip install web3. its giving me this error

Running setup.py install for lru-dict ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

```
× Running setup.py install for lru-dict did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [9 lines of output]
running install
C:\Users\Rishi Garg personal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
warnings.warn(
running build
running build_ext
building 'lru' extension
lru.c
C:\Users\Rishi Garg personal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file
error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure
× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lru-dict

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
PS C:\Users\Rishi Garg personal\demos\web3_py_simple_storage> python deploy.py
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Rishi Garg personal\demos\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py", line 7, in
from web3 import Web3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web3'
```

Comment: [Please see the answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory) how to set up your development environment properly.

Answer (score 1):

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lru-dict

^^^^

I would suggest installing this package and seeing what error you get.  That's the issue.  pip install lru-dict

Comment: I did that, its giving me this error
Collecting lru-dict
  Using cached lru-dict-1.1.7.tar.gz (10 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: lru-dict
  Building wheel for lru-dict (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Comment: python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'lru' extension
      lru.c
      c:\users\rishi garg personal\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file 
or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.30.30705\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2  
      [end of output]

Comment: note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lru-dict
  Running setup.py clean for lru-dict
Failed to build lru-dict
Installing collected packages: lru-dict
  Running setup.py install for lru-dict ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for lru-dict did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      running install

Comment: c:\users\rishi garg personal\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'lru' extension
      lru.c
      c:\users\rishi garg personal\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file 
or directory

Comment: error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.30.30705\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2  
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lru-dict

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed pip install python-dev-tools

Comment: its giving me this error, how to fix this?
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Rishi Garg personal\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-edkfgrgd\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic Python and Windows installation issue for any Python packages needing to compile native librariries.

[It is answered in detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory) how to install required Microsoft development tools.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of things and the best way to solve this is using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

Here are the links:

- https://medium.com/@cromewar/how-to-setup-windows-10-11-for-smart-contract-development-and-brownie-e7d8d13555b3
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-3---enable-virtual-machine-feature

Here is more info but no need it:

- https://medium.com/@cromewar/the-mighty-cytools-error-at-web3-smart-contract-development-with-brownie-63335d50f230

Answer (score 0):

Check your C++ version. I was able to install the lib once I installed [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)